# Relationships - Filtering Child Entries

Tags: relationships

I’ve started trying to figure out how relationships work and I have two channels (parentChannel and childChannel).

My data looks like this:

- parentChannel - title - “Item Name”
- childChannel - title - “2013 Item Name” , “2012 Item Name”, etc, etc

Within one of my templates, I would like to show some childChannel data, but I want to filter it to only the newest entry - in this case the 2013 entry.

How would I accomplish this?  Should I be “filtering” my childChannel data by some other means than the title itself, such as a category?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue with the following code:

```
{channel_relationship orderby="title" sort="desc" limit="1"}
```

I create a relationship field between the parentChannel and childChannel called channel_relationship.  Since the child fields all start with a year and I wanted to only display information from the newest year, I sorted all of the relationship entries by title, descending.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of do this:

1. to turn the parentChannel into a category group;
2. to create a category or a field to save the year of the item name on childChannel;

To avoid duplicated data, I prefer the number 1.